# Reverse engineering of logic board

Tags: jtag, reverse-engineering, nxp

I'm  trying to do some reverse engineering and  want to know if there is a way to reprogram the controllers of a board like this one. I know usually the manufacturers have some pins on the boards which are used to program, fix and debug boards but this one looks quite complex, at least for me.

I have this device for learn more about electronics and my main goal is reprogram with some basic functionalities.

Based on the documentation of the main controller, i need a JTAG port to program it. This board have a ton of test points so i think maybe some of then are used to interact with the board and not only for test.

[image]

[image]

- 1  MSP430F149 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f149.pdf)
- 2  K4M56163PG [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/168208/SAMSUNG/K4M56163PG-BG75.html)
- 3  256M29EWH  [datasheet](http://www.micron.com/~/media/Documents/Products/Data%20Sheet/NOR%20Flash/Parallel/M29EW/m29ew_256mb_2gb.pdf)
- 4  K4M56163PG [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/168208/SAMSUNG/K4M56163PG-BG75.html)
- 5  MC9328MXLDVM20 [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/files-static/32bit/doc/data_sheet/MC9328MXL.pdf)

I know this is a abstract question but any help or suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Reprogram it to do what? Without a schematic, you risk damage to the board. Have you reconstructed the schematic?

Comment: This is just for learning so don't have a specific goal of what to do. I think reconstruct the schematic is not an easy task, this board have few layers. I know if i have the schematic is easier to locate where specific pins are located.

Comment: If you don't know what pins have what functions, you can't do anything with it. And no, JTAG is not a requirement. It might be even disabled to prevent reverse engineering - it seems to be a medical device. The CPU can have a bootloader so it might even boot a file from SD card, who knows. At least it has a serial port bootloader built-in, but it can be difficult to find pins how to enable it. So there can be a debug serial port, or it may be disabled to prevent reverse engineering.

Comment: In the first image, right side, connector J1 is connected other simple board which have a serial port on it. In the documentation looks like there is a specific software for that, i was thinking maybe is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

There's two microcontrollers on this board:

- an MSP430 from TI, a low-power 16-bit MCU which is often used for sensor integration
- an i.MX type from NXP, a highly-integrated ARM SoC.

Each will likely have its own program / debug header that uses JTAG or some other debug interface. **J1** is the one for the i.MX, and it probably follows this pinout for Cortex debugging:

[image]

From here: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/jlink/jLink_connectors.htm

Not sure about the MSP430. The staggered row of test points on the back may be for that device, used for in-system programming with a bed of nails fixture.